# How does Facebook calculate mutual friends?

Tags: database, database-design, mysql, facebook

How does Facebook calculate mutual friends?

Does it cache all mutual friends for each user? Does it use MySQL to calculate mutual friends with a query?

Comment: I've not used facebook, but I'll still guess they use some fairly standard graph theory technique. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation to get some ideas.

Comment: Facebook uses their proprietary graph database to do these calculations. A more interesting question would be how one could do them with a SQL (or other non-proprietary) database.

Comment: It is an M-M relationship. Same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009025/facebook-database-design

Comment: My guess is that its done w/ MapReduce

Answer (score 13):

According to [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12070&ref_query=mutual%20frie),

> Mutual friends are the people who are Facebook friends with both you and the person whose profile you are viewing. For instance, if you are friends with Chris, and Mark is friends with Chris, then Chris will be shown as a mutual friend when you are viewing Mark's profile.

So, the set of mutual friends is the intersection of the set of your friends and the set of friends of the person you are viewing. If we assume that Facebook maintains an active cache of your friends, then when you view a person's page, another list containing that person's friends is retrieved, and the intersection of these two lists is the list of mutual friends.

Comment: Who knew that Charles Dickens would be so prophetic?

Comment: What?? Very Simple, I thought they are using graphs DS to manage them